# Where did the name for the Nz function come from?

Tags: vba

Was just curious - does `Nz` stands for something in particular? Doesn't seem obvious why it's named as it is.

[About the Nz function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php):

> The Microsoft Access Nz function lets you return a value when a variant is null.
>
> The syntax for the Microsoft Access Nz function is:
>
> `Nz ( variant, [ value_if_null ] )`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it stands for "null to zero".

If the argument is null, it returns 0. The idea is, you can sum several fields/values without worrying if any of them are null:

```
result = Nz(a) + Nz(b) + Nz(c)
```

Normally, null propagates through expressions, so that if you combine several values and *any one* of them is null, the result is also null. Converting "null to zero" prevents that.